# jQuery .delegate not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal

The following code works to toggle a class when page loads, but does not work after an Ajax call.

The html ([field_map_location] is a Drupal token):

```
<div class="clearfix dir-map">
<a href="#" class="show">Map</a>
<div id="slidingDiv" class="outside">
[field_map_location]
</div>
</div>
```

The javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.dir-map').delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).next('div').toggleClass('outside inside');
    });
});

});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
I've tried the following recommended solution and is still does not work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {
    $(document).delegate('.dir-map a', 'click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).next('div').toggleClass('outside inside');
    });
});
</script>
```

Sorry, I'm a noobie, so I don't know how to present to you the code for the AJAX call. I can tell you that this html is part of a Drupal view and I'm using its AJAX capability.

Comment: Show the Ajax call code that makes it not work.

Comment: (not an answer to your problem, but) It's unnecessary to use `jQuery(function($) { $(document).ready(function () {}); });` - you're just wrapping a ready handler with a ready handler.

Comment: Where's the Ajax call? What does it change?

Comment: Are you sure that `.dir-map` elements are stable and non-changing? You may need to use a higher level container

Comment: At least for verifying try this  `$(document).delegate('.dir-map a', 'click', function (e) {` probably in ajax call you are overwriting the `.dir-map`

Comment: tried this, but still no luck: `<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).delegate('.dir-map a', 'click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
   $(this).next('div').toggleClass('outside inside');
  });
});
</script>`

Comment: Seriously, you need to show the part that does the Ajax call.

Comment: This noobie doesn't know where to find that. I'm using Drupal, if that helps.

Comment: At this point it's pretty much impossible to say anything without further information. Chances are the Ajax call is removing all `.dir-map` elements altogether.

Comment: If you mean, are the .div-map elements being reloaded? Yes, they are. I don't know enough about delegate to know if that is important. If I need to pull back to an element that does not change, I can do that. e.g., `$(stable-element).delegate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drupal can be funny with AJAX at times; hooking into Drupal's own JS behaviors system might help...

```
(function($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.custom = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      $('.dir-map a', context).click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).next('div').toggleClass('outside inside');
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

The somewhat archaic event attaching is because Drupal 7 still ships with jQuery 1.4.2.

Comment: THANK YOU! You are spot on. Now, I just have to learn how to do this for myself.

Comment: [This link](http://drupal.org/node/304258) will be invaluable :) (look for "Drupal.behaviors practical example")

Comment: Thanks for the link. Will there be an issue with this code with jQuery Update?

Comment: Shouldn't be, all of the above is compatible with the latest version of jQuery, it's just a bit 'old school'